# merge two files based on one column Awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to merge two tab delimited files files - which are of unequal lengths. 
I need to merge the files based on column number 1 and get the values from the 3rd column of each file to the new file. If any of the files is missing any id ( uncommon value) then it should get a blank value in the new file -

```
File1: 
id1 2199 082
id2 0909 20909
id3 8002 8030
id4 28080 80828

File2:

id1 988 00808
id2 808 80808
id4 8080 2525
id6 838 3800

Merged file :

id1 082 00808
id2 20909 80808
id3 8030  
id4 80828 2525
id6   3800
```

I went through many forums and posts and so far I have this

```
awk -F\t 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$1; B[$1]=$1; next} {$2=A[$1]; $3=B[$1]}1'
```

but it does not yield the right result, can anyone please suggest. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$3; next} {A[$1]; B[$1]=$3} END{for (id in A) print id,A[id],B[id]}' OFS='\t' File1 File2 | sort
id1     082     00808
id2     20909   80808
id3     8030
id4     80828   2525
id6             3800
```

#### How it works

This script uses two variables.  For every line in File1, associative array `A` has a key corresponding to the id and the value of the third field.  For every id in File2, `A` also has a key (but not necessarily a value).  For File2, array `B` has a key for every id with the corresponding value from the third column.

- `-F'\t'`

  This sets the field separator on input to a tab.  Note that `\t` must be quoted to protect it from the shell.
- `NR==FNR{A[$1]=$3; next}`

  This sets the associative array `A` for the first file.
- `A[$1]; B[$1]=$3`

  This sets associative array for the second file.  It also makes sure that the array `A` has a key for every id in file2.
- `END{for (id in A) print id,A[id],B[id]}`

  This prints out the results.
- `OFS='\t'`

  This sets the output field separator to a tab.
- `sort`

  The awk construct `for key in array` is not guaranteed to return the keys in any particular order.  We use `sort` to sort the output into ascending order in the id.

Comment: Thanks a lot John! It works perfect and your explanation really helps in understanding how to modify command.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming no repeated IDs, you could try  (Bash used at `-F$'\t'`):

```
awk -F$'\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } NR==FNR { A[$1] = $3; next }
             { if ($1 in A) print $1, A[$1], $3
               else         print $1, " ", $3
               delete A[$1]
             }
             END { for (i in A) print i, A[i], " " }
            ' File1 File2
```

Set the output field separator.  For lines in the first file, capture field 3 of the first file in the array `A` indexed by column 1.  For lines in the second (or subsequent) files, if the ID column is found in `A`, print the three columns; otherwise, print a blank in place of the missing entry in `A`.  Delete the entries in `A` after they've been used.  At the end, any rows left over are printed with a blank for the missing entry in the second file.

For the given data, an example of the output is:

```
id1     082     00808
id2     20909   80808
id4     80828   2525
id6             3800
id3     8030
```

Clearly, if you want the data sorted in a particular way, you can post-filter the `awk` command with the `sort` command (meaning, pipe the output from `awk` to `sort`).

Comment: No need for `$'\t'` making it bash-specific, awk expands `'\t'` as desired in this case.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I do not need the results in the sorted order so this works  well as well!

Answer (score 3):

another similar `awk`

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$3; next} 
                          {$2=$3; $3=a[$1]; delete a[$1]} 1;   
                       END{for(k in a) print k,"",a[k]} ' file2 file1

id1     082     00808
id2     20909   80808
id3     8030
id4     80828   2525
id6             3800
```

used file2 first to match the output given but ordering is not guaranteed, if your keys have a natural order you can sort by them.

Comment: Thanks a lot karakfa..Now I have couple of awk options to learn from!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for `sorted_in`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{ a[$1] = (NR>FNR ? a[$1] OFS : "") $3 }
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for (k in a) {
        print k, a[k]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
id1     082     00808
id2     20909   80808
id3     8030
id4     80828   2525
id6             3800
```

With other awks just pipe the output to `sort`.